# Reloading/Refreshing Part of a Report Only

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have use case where I would like to control what is displayed on a map using a linear gauge (in edit mode) from Maps Pro and Widgets Pro.  In other words, when I change the value on the linear gauge, I would like the values on the map to change.  I know I can probably do this by refreshing the whole report.  However, I was wondering if there was a better AJAX like way of doing this using iReports Designer and Jaspersoft Reports server.  There are other tables and the such on the page, I have no need to refresh.

I am guessing the answer to this is probably no, based on what I know of Jasper so far.  However, I would like to do my due diligence and ask?

Please let me know if there is a way to do this.  How cool would this be?  It would be even cooler if I could change the values on the map as the pointer on the linear gauge was changing.

Thanks in advance.